# Views' taxonomy term page by content type

Tags: views

I have two regular content type **Article** & **Blog**, both share a term reference field **field_tags**. When I use **Taxonomy term** view that come with Views module, it display tags term in both content type.

For example, there are two Article nodes tag as **health** and three Blog nodes tag as **health**. Then if I use **Taxonomy term** view to display **health** term, it will display five nodes: two Article nodes and three Blog nodes.

Is there a way to separate the display result by content type? For example, if user click on health term on an Article node, Taxonomy term view will only display two Article nodes and if user click on health term on a Blog node, Taxonomy term view will show three Blog nodes.

Prefer not to use an extra module or adding different tag field for Blogs content type. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

in the view you can filter by your desired content type.

just add the filter criteria named *Content: type*

Comment: Thank you for reply. But if I add filter criteria for Content: type (Article) then when user click on term link on Blog node, nothing will show.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using Contextual filters in your view. Filter by Content:type and then provide the value in the URL.